# Motivation for Hypercohomology

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Someone can explain to me this bit from the wikipedia article on hypercohomology:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperhomology

> It turns out hypercohomology gives techniques for constructing a
> similar cohomological associated long exact sequence from an arbitrary
> long exact sequence $$ 0 \rightarrow M_{1} \rightarrow M_{2}
>  \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow M_{k} \rightarrow 0 $$ since its inputs
> are given by chain complexes instead of just objects from an abelian
> category. We can turn this chain complex into a distinguished triangle
> (using the language of triangulated categories on a derived category)
>
> $$ M_{1} \rightarrow\left[M_{2} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow M_{k-1}\right] \rightarrow M_{k}[-k+3] \stackrel{+1}{\longrightarrow}$$

I don't understand how it can be a distinguished triangle, I tried to disentangle the given triangle but I couldn't quite figure out what the morphisms are.

Plus I wanted to ask why one might want to consider hypercohomology at all, or cohomology of sequences made by chain complexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following diagram:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
&&&& 0 \\
&&&& @VVV \\
&&&& M_1 && 0 \\
&&&& @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> M_1 @>>> M_2 @>>> C @>>> 0 \\
& @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> 0 @>>> M_3 @>>> M_3 @>>> 0 \\
& @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
&& \vdots && \vdots && \vdots && \\
& @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> 0 @>>> M_{k-2} @>>> M_{k-2} @>>> 0 \\
& @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> 0 @>>> M_{k-1} @>>> M_{k-1} @>>> 0 \\
&&&& @VVV @VVV \\
&&&& M_k && M_k \\
&&&& @VVV @VVV \\
&&&& 0 && 0
\end{CD}$$

The rows are exact, so we have a distinguished triangle, $M_1 [0] \to [M_2 \to \cdots \to M_{k-1}] \to [C \to \cdots M_{k-1}] \to $.
But the columns are also exact, so we have the following quasi-isomorphism:
$$\begin{CD}
C @>>> 0 \\
@VVV @VVV \\
M_3 @>>> 0 \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\vdots && \vdots \\
@VVV @VVV \\
M_{k-2} @>>> 0 \\
@VVV @VVV \\
M_{k-1} @>>> M_k
\end{CD}$$
Hence we have the claimed distinguished triangle $M_1 [0] \to [M_2 \to \cdots \to M_{k-1}] \to M_k [-k + 3] \to$.

Comment: Thanks! So the quasi-isomorphism is given by the fact that $[C \to \cdots \to M_{k-1}]$ is a left resolution of $M_k$. That's truly wild, also is a distinguished triangle because it is an exact sequence of complexes

Comment: Yes, distinguished triangles come from short exact sequences of complexes, up to quasi-isomorphism.

Comment: So this is the reason why hypercohomology was introduced? Is there any other motivation for taking cohomology of sequences of complexes? Perhaps the holomorphic de Rham sequence and the Fröhlicher spectral sequence?

Comment: I don't really understand the claim that this is the reason for introducing hypercohomology. I prefer to believe the story that is told about derived functors and derived categories (i.e. the story that resolutions compute a finer invariant than just the cohomology groups).

Comment: In which sense resolutions compute a finer invariant? In the derived category you could lift the notion of an object to its resolution (via localizing on quasi-isomorphisms) but I'm truly having a hard time understanding why one might want to compute cohomology on a whole complex instead of taking a resolution of single objects. Perhaps to have a "global understanding" whenever you have a complex and a resolution for each object in the complex?

Comment: Do you have any reference/notes that can be helpful? I'm aware of S.I. Gelfand, Yu.I. Manin Homological Algebra, it provides lots of motivations which are great, but nowadays I'm studying Hodge theory and I've been having some trouble putting everything in context. Btw thanks for all your clarifications.

Comment: If you compose two derived functors then you inevitably have to compute the value of the second derived functor on a complex obtained by applying the first derived functor, even if you started with a mere object.